# запрет доступа к файлу через .htaccess deny

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Добавляю в .htaccess:

```html
<files 1.png>
Deny
</files>
```

Файл domain.com/1.png все равно открывается. Как правильно запретить доступ к файлу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Files "index.php">  Order Deny,Allow  Deny from all </Files>
```